# How to switch context between .net framework 4 and .net standard 1.5 for Task.Delay

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, task

I have a project that i'm migrating over to asp.net core and I'm getting this error: 
[image]

And below here is my project.json file

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "AutoMapper": "3.2.1",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3"

  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81"

      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-rc2-24027",
        "System.Linq.Expressions": "4.0.11-rc2-24027"
      }

    },
    "net40": {

      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Bcl.Async": "1.0.168"


      }
    }

  }
}
```

How do I pick that I want to use the Task.Delay tat is available in the .net standard 1.5 and ignore the .net framework 4.  Do I have to have them available in both??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use preprocessor directives to do this as described here: https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/libraries/libraries-with-cli.html

```
#if NETSTANDARD1_5
    //do something that's just on netstandard1.5
#else
    //do something that's not NET40
#endif
```

Comment: This seems to do the job, thanks so much.  I wonder how much this is going to have to happen when .netcore gets more traction from user and the community.  I feel like this is a sloppy way around the problem.

Comment: @JeremyConterio: Pretty often if you want to support for unsupported .NET Frameworks (.NET 4 is quite old and not actively supported anymore, just 4.5.1 or 4.5.2 and higher). .NET Core is based on System.Runtime (introduced for WinRT), which was first introduced in .NET 4.5 but since then it has many additions until now